# Why are there two pulls under 'Team' in Eclipse (Git) ? Any difference?

Tags: eclipse, git

When you right-click your project, and go to Team to use Git. I see two pull just like the screenshot below.

[image]

Does anyone know the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- ***Pull*** pulls from the upstream branch of the remote repository **without opening a dialog** (that's what you want to do in most cases).
- ***Pull...*** opens a **dialog** (`...` means a dialog will be opened) where you can define **where you want to pull from** (e. g. if you have more than one remote repository).

Comment: well explained!   Thank you